# How can I use netcat (nc) for chat client server model?

Tags: bash, netcat

I am trying to write a daemon using `bash`. I will enter my partner's IP address and the connection will start using `nc partner_ip 2015`, likewise on the server I will start the connection using `nc -l -p 2015`.

I want to print my name every time I send a message and also to print my partner's name before his message. So first I need to work out my partner's username and IP address.

```
#! /bin/bash

function readPip()
{
    echo "Enter your partener IP"
    read ip
    export PIP= $ip
}


function readMip()
{
    mip=ip addr list eth0 |grep "inet " |cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d/ -f1
    echo -n "'my IP is"$mip"
    export MIP=$mip
}

function chat()
{
    [[ $PIP != " " ]]&& nc $PIP 2015
    [[ $PIP == " " ]] && nc -l -p 2015
}
function testConnect()
{
    nc $PIP 2015  > /dev/null
    echo "am here"
    return $1
}

readPip
testConnect
readMip
echo "$1"
```

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? Can you show us what you have achieved so far?

Comment: am in my first steps in bash it is my second program so do not laugh

Comment: As a community we are all here to help and learn from one another.

Comment: @user2278127 : It's hard to read code in comments! It's **much** easier to read if you paste it into your question as a code block (select your code then hit the `{}` button). Tiny bits of code are ok in comments, but when putting code into comments you should surround it with `backticks` so stuff doesn't get treated as formatting commands.

Comment: okay I edited the post now

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: does not do what i want it to do

Comment: As the syntax highlighting shows, you need to fix the quotes in `echo -n "'my IP is"$mip"`.

Comment: OR, do according to this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665492/how-to-build-a-simple-chat-using-netcat?rq=1) As simple as that!

Answer (score 2):

> `function readPip()`
>   `{`
>   `echo "Enter your partener IP"`
>   `read ip`
>   `export PIP= $ip`
>   `}`

The space after the equals sign is a syntax error. But in addition, all of this could be refactored to just

```
readPip () {
    read -p "Enter your partner's IP: " PIP
}
```

The `export` is unnecessary as you don't need external child processes to have access to this variable.

> `function readMip()`
>   `{`
>   `mip=ip addr list eth0 |grep "inet " |cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d/ -f1`
>   `echo -n "'my IP is"$mip"`
>   `export MIP=$mip`
>   `}`

Again, this contains an error; you assign to `mip` the value `ip` and then (try to) run the command `addr list ...`, where apparently the intent is to run `ip addr list ...` and assign the result of that to `MIP`.

```
readMip () {
    ip addr list eth0 |grep "inet " |cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d/ -f1`
}
```

Here, I would simply leave the assignment to the caller (`readPip` could be refactored the same way for consistency).

In the main code, you'd have

```
MIP=$(readMip)
```

Again, the `export` is neither necessary nor useful.

> `function chat()`
>   `{`
>   `[[ $PIP != " " ]]&& nc $PIP 2015`
>   `[[ $PIP == " " ]] && nc -l -p 2015`
>   `}`

This is clearly "if - then - else" and should be written accordingly.

```
chat () {
    if [[ "$PIP" == " " ]]; then
        nc -l -p 2015
    else
        nc "$PIP" 2015
    fi
}
```

or even

```
[[ "$PIP" == " " ]] && nc -l -p 2015 || nc "$PIP" 2015
```

Notice also that I dropped the Bash-only `function` keyword. You still have a couple of Bashisms here but those could trivially be refactored for a POSIX-portable script.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both `nc` calls with unbuffered `sed` calls:

```
sed -u "s/^/My name: /" | nc PARTNER_IP 2015

sed -u "s/^/Partner name: /" | nc -l 2015
```

Comment: #! /bin/bash
function readPip()
{
 echo "Enter your partener IP"
 read ip
 export PIP= $ip
}


function readMip()
{
 mip=ip addr list eth0 |grep "inet " |cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d/ -f1
 echo -n "'mكIP is"$mip"
 export MIP=$mip
}

function chat()
{
 [[ $PIP != " " ]]&& nc $PIP 2015
 [[ $PIP == " " ]] && nc -l -p 2015
}
function testConnect()
{
 nc $PIP 2015  > /dev/null
 echo "am here"
 return $1
}

readPip
testConnect
readMip
echo "$1"

Comment: that is my code where should i replace it

Comment: code is duplicated i think that at least 2 functions are doing the same work am i right?

Comment: when sed -u "s/^/My name: /" | nc 127.0.0.1 2015
(UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 2015 (?) : Connection refused